# How to calculate gate capacitances (Cgs,Cgd) of a GaN HEMT?

Tags: transistors, capacitance

I have calculated Cgd and Cgs using an analytical model, And I found that the second one is negative for Vgs < Vth, where Vth is threshold voltage and Vgs is the applied voltage. could this be possible and why ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It's possible if your formulas are wrong.

Comment: Consider posting the formulas and maybe an abbreviated part of your work?

Comment: The formulas are a bit longer so I am going just to include the article from which I used these formulas. I really appreciate your help                                                    Here is the article "A physics based compact model of I–V and C–V characteristics in AlGaN/GaN HEMT devices"